# Symfony 2, form and jQuery on change submit

Tags: php, forms, symfony, routes

I want to create form with auto submit, so I used jquery. I think that i have problem with translate url.

My form :

```
<form action="edit" method="get" >
    <select name="id" onchange="this.form.submit();">
        {% for panel in panele %}
        <option value="{{ panel.setting.id }}">{{ panel.nazwa }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
</form>
```

And when I want to change option, I get this in url "`edit?id={id}`", and when i try use it in controller (route).

```
@Route("/edit?id={id}")
```

I got error:

> No route found for "GET /settings/edit"

(`/settings` is global route for controller)

Answer (score 1):

The `action attribute` of your form has no URL. Your should generate the url using twig path expression.

```
<form action="{{ path('edit_route') }}" method="get" >
```

Replace the route identifier `edit_route` with the name of your route. **Also, clear browser and symfony caches.**